# Windows 2008 R2 guest on Hyper-V R1

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I am trying to test Server 2008 R2 by installing it on a virtual machine running under Hyper-V on Server 2008 R1.  Unfortunately, every time I try to install it from the .ISO image, I get a prompt to insert a driver disk.  I have tried this on three separate Hyper-V servers with the same result on each one.  Is there a driver disk I am somehow missing?  According to Microsoft, running a Server 2008 R2 guest is supported ( http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-supported-guest-os.aspx ).  Has anyone else run into this problem?  How did you get around it?

Comment: You may wish to advise your VM settings. How are you connecting the VHD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .ISO was bad.  The hash code did not match the one posted on the Microsoft site.  I was able to dig up another .ISO on our network that worked like a charm

Comment: When we're moving big ISO images around, this happens *a lot* more often than we would like to think. Cosmic rays are out to get you!